# ignore folder with specific ending using glob

Tags: javascript, glob

I try to find all project.json files in all subdirectories of a specific folder:

```
import glob from 'glob'

glob.sync('apps/**/project.json', {
    ignore: ['apps/**-e2e/project.json']
})
```

This gives me a result like:

```
[
    'apps/something/project-e2e/project.json',
    'apps/something/project/project.json'
]
```

I would like to ignore all folders, which ends with `e2e`. Is this possible. My attempt using the `ignore` part doesn't work

Comment: Did you try `apps/**/**-e2e/project.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `/*`, perhaps the `**` doesn't allow for partial directory names

```js
import glob from 'glob'

glob.sync('apps/**/project.json', {
    ignore: ['apps/**/*-e2e/project.json']
})
```